# Do all the calories affect the weight gain in a same way?

Tags: nutrition, calories, weight-gain

Usually, the amount of food person needs to eat to stay in the same shape is measured in calories : i.e if one consumes less - he loses the weight, and in the opposite situation - there is a weight gain. But are the things as simple? Because, the same amount of calories can be consituted in very different way - like 100g of butter have a 700-800 calories, and the same amount of cooked chicken breast has 160 calories.

Assuming the daily norm to be 2500 calories, disregarding the fact, that hardly anyone could eat only chicken or butter whole day along and that any healthy nutritition, or at least sensible one requieres a balance between fat, carbohydrates, proteins - would the person, who eats chicken the whole day and another hypothetic person eating this 300-350 g piece of butter satisfy equally their need of energy?

Or more realistic question, if one wants to gain weight without consuming large amount of foods, the best strategy would be to eat a lot of sweets and cookies, rich in calories, or eating a certain amount of chicken and cottage cheese, say, with 5-10% calories less, than in the former case for junk foods, but with the higher net mass may also lead to the same result?

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question as it serves as a learning opportunity for how nutrition quality and quantity can impact fitness differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All calories are equal, but the sources of those calories are not.

Let's look at the calories themselves first. A certain amount of body mass will require a certain amount of energy to sustain itself and activity imposes additional energy costs. The body manages an energy surplus by storing the extra energy and the body manages an energy deficit by using up stored energy to make up the difference. This is true regardless of the source of calories consumed.

Looking at the macronutrients' contribution to energy balance we have the following; [1]

- Protein contains 4 kCal/g and costs about 1 kCal/g to use that energy.
- Carbohydrates contain 4 kCal/g and costs about 0.4 kCal/g to use that energy.
- Fat contains about 9 kCal/g and costs about 0.3 kCal/g to use that energy.

This means to match a traditional stick of butter of 113 grams (let's simplify to say it's only 92 grams of fat), you would need to consume 2452 grams of egg whites (let's simplify to say that it's only 266.5 grams of protein). If we compare raw calorie values it's 828 vs 1066, but when we compare the net calories we actually get from the foods it's an equal 800.

But within the realm of physical fitness we know that food does more than merely influence energy balance. Carbs aid in glycolytic energy pathways that influence performance in short duration, high intensity activities. Fats aid in hormone production, and proteins are the building blocks of many tissues. Each serve additional purposes, but to put it simply you might consider the macronutrients role as being more important with regard to health and performance as opposed to energy balance. Micronutrients are exclusively health and performance related since they contain no energy.

**Here's the bottom line. Energy balance will always have the same end result regardless of the source of calories consumed. However, health and performance outcomes will vary.**

---

[1]: [https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4258944/#:~:text=The%20thermic%20effect%20of%20food,metabolism%20and%20storage%20of%20nutrients](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4258944/#:%7E:text=The%20thermic%20effect%20of%20food,metabolism%20and%20storage%20of%20nutrients)).